# How to find a specific pattern of text with spaces followed by a date or digits anywhere in the string using regular expressions in R

Tags: r, regex, grepl

I want to use grepl() and regular expressions to find what percentage of my dataset can be captured with a few statements that all mean essentially the same thing.

the string will say something like this "...activity between the dates 2/2/21 and 3/5/2021..."

Im hoping to use grepl() to find a the phrase "between the dates" with spaces followed by a space followed by a number somewhere in the string.

So far I have attempted many variations of `grepl("(.*?)between the dates [0-9]+", df2$text, fixed = TRUE)` but with no success. What am I doing wrong?

to be more clear on the error here is an example:
text = "this sentence contains info about activity between the dates 2/2/21 and 3/5/2021 and the details about that activity."

```
text = "this sentence contains info about activity between the dates 2/2/21 and 3/5/2021 and the details about that activity." 
ifelse(grepl("between the dates", text, fixed = TRUE),1,0)   
ifelse(grepl("(.*?)between the dates [0-9]+", text, fixed = TRUE),1,0)
```

The first ifelse using grepl and no regular expressions returns 1 while the send ifelse using grepl and regular expressions returns 0.

Comment: What do you mean by "no success"?  Please give an example for which this is not performing as expected.

Comment: thanks for your assistance. Ive updated the post to include an example of what i mean

Comment: @omaromaromar it works with `perl = TRUE`, or using `str_detect()`. Update: also without `fixed = TRUE`